# Why isn't MavensMate picking up changes that I make directly on the config files?

Tags: picklist, mavensmate, package.xml

I have an existing MavensMate project and I want to include StandardValueSets.

I edited package.xml in Sublime and included the list of StandardValueSets provided here - http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2016/11/24/standard-picklist-changes-winter-17/

When I open the project in MavensMate it does not show any entries under StandardValueSet.

I tried a similar thing for the metadata subscription - I edited .settings in Sublime to include all the metadata that I want to subscribe to, rather than ticking each box in MM.  As with the above though, MM does not detect the changes that I have made manually when I re-open the project.

What step am I missing?

Thanks.

Following Akram's advice to 'Refresh from Server', I now have the metadata locally, but still not showing in MM:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh from Sandbox:

In Sublime text:
- Right click on "src" folder
- Go to "Mavens Mate" then "Refresh from Server"

It will take a while to refresh all the metadata described in the package.xml

Comment: Thanks - the standardValueSets have downloaded locally, but still don't show in MM:

Comment: Why you need them in MM ? StandardValueSet components are available in API version 38.0 and later, not sure if they are available in MM try forcing the API version to 38 or above in MM Settings.

Comment: Fair point Akram that it's not really needed, I have already deployed it to another org.  It would be good to have a consistent picture in MM of which metadata is downloaded though.

Comment: My second point was that manual edits to .settings (much easier to paste in the metadata subscription) are not getting picked up in MM either, so it seemed like I was missing a step somewhere to get MM to pick up my manual edits.

Comment: It makes sense to use the MM UI and not the .settigns because there is extra actions to do when you press "Update Subscription" and then "Refresh index"
This will update your package.xml and then do the "Refresh from Server" behind the scenes.

Comment: if this answer helped you, please mark the answer as the right one !